# Backup of postgres database giving ssl error

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, dbeaver

I have been using using DBeaver and I got a new laptop.  With a fresh install adding the postgres remote database exactly as it is in the other computer.
I can see all the tables and data in the database.  I just cannot take a backup.

When I right click tools->backup and I click start (same process works on old laptop) I am getting the error below.  If I do this with my local dev database it works fine as expected.  I can do a backup on my laptop both directly before and directly after trying on the new laptop.

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin\pg_dump.exe --format=c -n public --verbose --host=compute-1.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --username=elkjlkjkjyb d5kjhkjhjkht5
Backup started at Sun Sep 02 22:10:20 EDT 2018
pg_dump: last built-in OID is 16383
pg_dump: reading extensions
pg_dump: identifying extension members
pg_dump: reading schemas
pg_dump: reading user-defined tables
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: SSL error: sslv3 alert bad record mac
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: SELECT c.tableoid, c.oid, c.relname, (SELECT pg_catalog.array_agg(acl ORDER BY row_n) FROM (SELECT acl, row_n FROM pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(c.relacl,pg_catalog.acldefault(CASE WHEN c.relkind = 'S' THEN 's' ELSE 'r' END::"char",c.relowner))) WITH ORDINALITY AS perm(acl,row_n) WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(pip.initprivs,pg_catalog.acldefault(CASE WHEN c.relkind = 'S' THEN 's' ELSE 'r' END::"char",c.relowner))) AS init(init_acl) WHERE acl = init_acl)) as foo) AS relacl, (SELECT pg_catalog.array_agg(acl ORDER BY row_n) FROM (SELECT acl, row_n FROM pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(pip.initprivs,pg_catalog.acldefault(CASE WHEN c.relkind = 'S' THEN 's' ELSE 'r' END::"char",c.relowner))) WITH ORDINALITY AS initp(acl,row_n) WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(c.relacl,pg_catalog.acldefault(CASE WHEN c.relkind = 'S' THEN 's' ELSE 'r' END::"char",c.relowner))) AS permp(orig_acl) WHERE acl = orig_acl)) as foo) as rrelacl, NULL AS initrelacl, NULL as initrrelacl, c.relkind, c.relnamespace, (SELECT rolname FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles WHERE oid = c.relowner) AS rolname, c.relchecks, c.relhastriggers, c.relhasindex, c.relhasrules, c.relhasoids, c.relrowsecurity, c.relforcerowsecurity, c.relfrozenxid, c.relminmxid, tc.oid AS toid, tc.relfrozenxid AS tfrozenxid, tc.relminmxid AS tminmxid, c.relpersistence, c.relispopulated, c.relreplident, c.relpages, CASE WHEN c.reloftype <> 0 THEN c.reloftype::pg_catalog.regtype ELSE NULL END AS reloftype, d.refobjid AS owning_tab, d.refobjsubid AS owning_col, (SELECT spcname FROM pg_tablespace t WHERE t.oid = c.reltablespace) AS reltablespace, array_remove(array_remove(c.reloptions,'check_option=local'),'check_option=cascaded') AS reloptions, CASE WHEN 'check_option=local' = ANY (c.reloptions) THEN 'LOCAL'::text WHEN 'check_option=cascaded' = ANY (c.reloptions) THEN 'CASCADED'::text ELSE NULL END AS checkoption, tc.reloptions AS toast_reloptions, c.relkind = 'S' AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_depend WHERE classid = 'pg_class'::regclass AND objid = c.oid AND objsubid = 0 AND refclassid = 'pg_class'::regclass AND deptype = 'i') AS is_identity_sequence, EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_attribute at LEFT JOIN pg_init_privs pip ON (c.oid = pip.objoid AND pip.classoid = 'pg_class'::regclass AND pip.objsubid = at.attnum)WHERE at.attrelid = c.oid AND ((SELECT pg_catalog.array_agg(acl ORDER BY row_n) FROM (SELECT acl, row_n FROM pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(at.attacl,pg_catalog.acldefault('c',c.relowner))) WITH ORDINALITY AS perm(acl,row_n) WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(pip.initprivs,pg_catalog.acldefault('c',c.relowner))) AS init(init_acl) WHERE acl = init_acl)) as foo) IS NOT NULL OR (SELECT pg_catalog.array_agg(acl ORDER BY row_n) FROM (SELECT acl, row_n FROM pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(pip.initprivs,pg_catalog.acldefault('c',c.relowner))) WITH ORDINALITY AS initp(acl,row_n) WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(at.attacl,pg_catalog.acldefault('c',c.relowner))) AS permp(orig_acl) WHERE acl = orig_acl)) as foo) IS NOT NULL OR NULL IS NOT NULL OR NULL IS NOT NULL))AS changed_acl, pg_get_partkeydef(c.oid) AS partkeydef, c.relispartition AS ispartition, pg_get_expr(c.relpartbound, c.oid) AS partbound FROM pg_class c LEFT JOIN pg_depend d ON (c.relkind = 'S' AND d.classid = c.tableoid AND d.objid = c.oid AND d.objsubid = 0 AND d.refclassid = c.tableoid AND d.deptype IN ('a', 'i')) LEFT JOIN pg_class tc ON (c.reltoastrelid = tc.oid) LEFT JOIN pg_init_privs pip ON (c.oid = pip.objoid AND pip.classoid = 'pg_class'::regclass AND pip.objsubid = 0) WHERE c.relkind in ('r', 'S', 'v', 'c', 'm', 'f', 'p') ORDER BY c.oid
Backup finished at Sun Sep 02 22:10:21 EDT 2018
Process exit code: 1
```

UPDATE

I believe this has to do with a large query problem instead of a ssl problem.  I did an insert with 50 rows and no problem.  As soon as i go over a certain number of characters it seems to break connecting to the server.  Also I believe the pg_dump is a problem because the query it tries to do is a very large query.  This is a local problem because it doesnt happen on my other laptop.

Probably some max setting in Postgres 10.5-2 or JDBC.  My old laptop has the same JDBC version as my new one.  Old laptop has Postgres 10.4-1 though.

Comment: try this command i don't know if this will give same error or not "pg_dump -U user -d database > filename.sql

Comment: did that using CMD and added host and port.  same error.

Comment: What error show up?

Comment: its in the post.  `pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: SSL error: sslv3 alert bad record mac`.

Comment: I updated my question because I think I narrowed it down to a large query size instead of a ssl problem

Answer (score 0):

So this turns out not to be related directly with Postgres.

I have a MSI GS65.  It has a hardware network driver called killer network.

The driver has settings you can modify.  One of those setting is to optimize network speeds.  It seems that this setting will drop larger connections.  When I am doing a backup or a large query through dbeaver, it drops the connection and stops the backup/query.

Took me 2 years to find this issue.  I hope this helps any devs with a MSI computer with network issues.